# Logstash Kafka config `ssl_keystore_location` not set

Tags: apache-kafka, logstash, kafka-consumer-api, elastic-stack

I am using logstash which takes input from kafka and writes the output to elastic search.
My input config looks like this:

```
input {
  kafka {
    bootstrap_servers => "my-aws-msk.kafka.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:9092"
    topics => ["agg_events"]
    group_id => "agg-logstash-consumer"
    consumer_threads => 2
    ssl_keystore_location => "/tmp/kafka.client.truststore.jks"
    ssl_truststore_location => "/tmp/kafka.client.truststore.jks"
  }
}
```

When logstash starts, it logs the consumer config. The keystore location that I have set above is null in the resultant config.

```
auto.commit.interval.ms = 5000
auto.offset.reset = latest
bootstrap.servers = [my-aws-msk.kafka.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:9092]
check.crcs = true
client.dns.lookup = default
client.id = logstash-1
connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
default.api.timeout.ms = 60000
enable.auto.commit = true
exclude.internal.topics = true
fetch.max.bytes = 52428800
fetch.max.wait.ms = 500
fetch.min.bytes = 1
group.id = agg-logstash-consumer
heartbeat.interval.ms = 3000
interceptor.classes = []
internal.leave.group.on.close = true
isolation.level = read_uncommitted
key.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
max.partition.fetch.bytes = 1048576
max.poll.interval.ms = 300000
max.poll.records = 500
metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
metric.reporters = []
metrics.num.samples = 2
metrics.recording.level = INFO
metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
partition.assignment.strategy = [class org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RangeAssignor]
receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
request.timeout.ms = 30000
retry.backoff.ms = 100
sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
sasl.jaas.config = null
sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
sasl.login.class = null
sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
send.buffer.bytes = 131072
session.timeout.ms = 10000
ssl.cipher.suites = null
ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
ssl.key.password = null
ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
***ssl.keystore.location = null***
ssl.keystore.password = null
ssl.keystore.type = JKS
ssl.protocol = TLS
ssl.provider = null
ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
ssl.truststore.location = null
ssl.truststore.password = null
ssl.truststore.type = JKS
value.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
```

What am I doing wrong here? Per the [source code](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-integration-kafka/blob/master/lib/logstash/plugin_mixins/kafka_support.rb#L11) they seem to be checking if the path is null. If it is not null, it should endup in the config.  But probably there is something I am missing here.

Comment: Not really sure, but have you considered using Kafka Connect Elasticsearch sink instead?

Answer (score 0):

Are you expecting to receive Kafka messages from the bootstrap server or sending them too?
If your receiving.

I would try

```
input {
   tcp{
    port => <port your listening on>
    type => kafka { 
            < ALL OF YOUR SETTINGS FROM KAFKA INPUT>
            }
    }
output {
 kafka {
  <kafka server info>
 }
}
```